# mysql query lowest option sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query returning the following:

```
ID | Price
---------------
1 | 20
1 | 30
1 | 15
2 | 10
2 | 12
2 | 20
3 | 1
3 | 0
3 | 0
4 | 0
4 | 0 
4 | 7
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can get the sum of the lowest value for each ID. So in this case it would return 25.
15+10+0+0

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery selecting the `min` price for each id, then `sum` those values:

```
select sum(minprice) as overallprice
from (
    select min(price) minprice
    from yourtable
    group by id) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub-query that finds the lowest price per id and take the results from that and sum them together.  In pseudo-code:

```
select
  sum(lowest_price)
from (select id, min(price) as lowest_price from prices group by id) lowest_prices
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query like  below

```
 Select sum (a) from
  (
     Select min (price) as a from yourtable
    Group by id
 ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using partition without using `group by` statement

```
select sum(price.min_price) from 
(select distinct id,min(price) over(partition by id) as min_price from prices) price
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland OP didn't ask for particular SQL version

Comment: i know i added the comment for future readers so they know this is a MySQL 8.0+ only query.

Comment: If you go down this route, you'll need to add `distinct` to the subquery.  Also move the `min_price` alias after the `over` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Some other approaches would be to use MySQL user variables or a self left join..

MySQL user variable solution

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 SUM(prices.Price)
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
     prices.Price
   , CASE 
       WHEN @id != prices.id    
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0 
     END AS isMinGroupValue
   , (@id := prices.id)    
  FROM 
    prices 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
      @id := 0
   ) AS init_user_params
  ORDER BY
     prices.ID ASC
   , prices.price ASC 
) AS prices
WHERE
  prices.isMinGroupValue = 1
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nzWqMQAxd7mvq589R7WuZ8/0

Self left join solution

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 SUM(prices1.Price)
FROM 
 prices prices1
LEFT JOIN
 prices prices2
ON
   prices1.ID = prices2.ID
 AND
   prices1.price > prices2.price
WHERE
 prices2.ID IS NULL
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nzWqMQAxd7mvq589R7WuZ8/1

Answer (score 0):

I would use *correlation* `subquery` :

```
select sum(t.price) as overallprice
from table t
where price = (select min(price) from table t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```